# Importrange Query

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I am stuck, I have tried multiply codes but I must have some kind of error in it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MnqgFF9wtk_9u57BC3mPqxxzUo7wkY4Ode7G-a6t_P8/edit#gid=958689010

I want to create my own filter with ID's I have assigned to categories. When I put in that certain ID, it will show me all categories levels automatically.

I assumed it will work with:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(eBayKategorie!A:G), "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A)&"'", 0)
```

But I get an error message. am I missing a . or ,?
Does someone know what I am missing?

I also tried to work with `Vlookup` and `named ranges`, also `query` only and `named ranges` but this only applies to one cell and seems overly complicated. It does work, but it looks like, it leaves a lot of room for mistakes (See tabs with VLOOKSUP in naming)

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, Katgegories,2,false)
```

All the best.

Comment: I would recommend checking how `IMPORTRANGE` is used as it seems you are only sending one parameter, see this [doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) If you can share what would be the expected outcome that would be great.

Comment: Hello @gabriel, thank you for your answer. I have also tried only `query` and `named range` now, maybe `Importrange` is not necessary if it's within the same sheet. But it also must be doing something wrong. 

My expected outcome is: I enter the ID manually into column C, and it pulls all the data what is behind the ID into Coloumn D-I. So I know ID XXX belongs to Kategorie 1-2-3-4-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMPORTRANGE` is a formula to get data from another spreadsheet.

do you need to import stuff from another spreadsheet?

if yes, the correct syntax is:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MnqgFF9wtk_9u57BC3mPqxxzUo7wkY4Ode7G-a6t_P8/edit#gid=958689010", "Register!A:G"), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)&"'", 0)
```

if you don't need to import stuff from a different spreadsheet but just a different sheet/tab use:

```
=QUERY({Register!A:G}, 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)&"'", 0)
```

in your case I believe you need:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, Register!A2:G, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. @player0 Thank you for your help! is there also a way to add into a formula: "that if no match is found, and outcome is empty, he can take the Info from Row 14 in "Index" sheet" I have changed the sheet accordingly so you can see what I mean. Thank you

Comment: @Guhlis try:  `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:INDEX(C:C, COUNTA(C:C)), INDEX!A2:G, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0), INDEX!B14:G14))`